# Can solr use wildcard character * in query filed like in fl parameter

Tags: solr

I have a lot of person data, single person data is as following

`personID: 1
  phoneNum1: 20 (the count of phone number 1 used is 20)
  phoneNum2: 22 (the count of phone number 2 used is 22)
  phoneNum3: 26 (the count of phone number 3 used is 26)
...`

How can I get the result by solr:

one: the person with id 1 uses the phone number 3 the most count

two: the person with id 1 has phone number 2 and 3 when the count used is bigger than 21, I want to use 'q=phoneNum*:[22 TO *]&fl=phoneNum*' but I know the first part doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic fields in schema file. like

`<dynamicField name="phoneNum*"  type="int"  indexed="true"  stored="true" />`

then you query like /select?q=phoneNum*:[22 TO ]

Comment: This should not work.
The error message is as following
"msg":"org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'p7_*:[19,49]': Encountered \" \":\" \": \"\" at line 1, column 4.\nWas expecting one of:\n ......